# Why would you use a public interface within a java db entity?

Tags: java, interface, pojo

I found this code snippet while looking at other projects and I was wondering on the benefit of having a public interface within a java pojo. Why should you use it as seen in the below example. Is the below use considered a best practice? Is there a catch with using an interface liek this?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_mapping", schema = "billing")
public class CustomerMapping {
    public interface createCustomerMapping {
    }

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonProperty("customerMappingId")
private Integer id;

@Column(length=10)
@NotNull(groups = { createCustomerMapping.class })
@NotEmpty(groups = { createCustomerMapping.class })
@Size(groups = { createCustomerMapping.class }, min = 4, max = 4)
private String issuerCode;

@Column(length=10)
@NotNull(groups = { createCustomerMapping.class })
@NotEmpty(groups = { createCustomerMapping.class })
private String offerCode;

@NotNull
private Long customerId;

@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createdTs;

private String createdBy;

@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updatedTs;

private String updatedBy;

public CustomerMapping(String offerCode) {
    this.offerCode = offerCode;
}

public CustomerMapping(String issuerCode, String offerCode) {
    this.issuerCode = issuerCode;
    this.offerCode = offerCode;
}

public CustomerMapping(String issuerCode, String offerCode, Long customerId) {
    this.issuerCode = issuerCode;
    this.offerCode = offerCode;
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
}
```

From what I know an interface is used to define a contract so I'm familiar with the implementation in using it via a library of code or if two teams needs to co-operate. But in the above example, its unclear to me.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation-advanced003.htm

Comment: Ah got it thanks. So most likely for simplicity the user decided to not create a separate file and just include the interface inline

Comment: Yes I think that's right.